# Smoothness of inertia stacks

Tags: ag.algebraic-geometry, reference-request, algebraic-stacks

Let $k$ be a field of characteristic zero. Let $X$ be a smooth DM stack over $k.$ Is the inertia stack $IX$ always smooth over $k$?

I believe this is true, but cannot find a proof in the literature. I would appreciate it if someone can give a proof or a reference of a proof.

PS: We do not assume $X$ is separated.

Answer (score 3):

Let X be a DM stack over a scheme S. X is called *tame* if its automorphism groups are of order invertible on S. For example, every DM stack over a field of characteristic zero is tame.

If X is tame and smooth over S, then the (relative) inertia stack $I_{X/S}$ is smooth over S.  This is because $I_{X/S}$ can be decomposed as the disjoint union of $Map^{repr}(B\mathbb{Z}/n, X)$, stack of representable maps $B\mathbb{Z}/n \to X$, over integers $n$ invertible on $S$. Each $G=\mathbb{Z}/n$ is linearly reductive over $S$ so these mapping stacks are smooth (the cotangent complex is the $G$-invariants of the cotangent complex $L_X$ pulled back to $BG$).

Comment: Let $X_n$ be a so-called mapping stack. Is it a DM stack? If yes, why? How does the smoothness of $X_n$ follow from the linear reductivity of $G=\mathbb{Z}/n\mathbb{Z}?$ Can you describe a smooth scheme $Y_n$ with a smooth surjective morphism $Y_n \to X_n?$

Comment: For a wild counterexample, one can take the quotient of $\mathbb A^2$ over a field of characteristic $p$ by the automorphism $(x,y) \to (x, y+x^2)$ of order $p$, whose inertia stack contains as a component (the quotient of) the fixed locus of this automorphism, which is non-reduced.

Comment: @YuhangChen Taking $G$-invariants is an exact functor when $G$ is linearly reductive, so the cotangent complex is still acyclic in negative degrees. Existence of such $Y_n$ follows from smoothness, yes. If you're not comfortable with the mapping stack, you can just describe the cotangent complex at a point of the inertia stack in the same way -- these points correspond to a point of the stack together with an automorphism at that point, and the cotangent complex at this point has the same description as in the answer where $G$ is the cyclic group generated by the automorphism.

Comment: @crystalline Thanks for the explanations. I am not familiar with both the mapping stacks and the cotangent complex of a DM stack or an Artin stack. But I think the existence of the decomposition of the inertia stack $IX$ into a disjoint union of mapping stacks requires a proof. You meant this decomposition is not required for a proof like this: the cotangent complex $L_{IX}$ pulled back to each $BG$ is perfect in degree zero, and hence so is $L_{IX}$, which proves that the inertia stack of a smooth tame DM stack is smooth. Did I understand correctly?

Comment: @YuhangChen Yes, sounds right.

Comment: @crystalline Why only "sounds" right? Is the following true: if the cotangent complex $L_Y$ of an Artin stack $Y$ pulled back to each point of $Y$ is perfect in degree zero, then so is $L_Y$?

Comment: @YuhangChen Yes (by the definition of perfect complexes on stacks), if by "point" you mean ring-valued or scheme-valued point.

Comment: @crystalline No, I meant $k$-valued point. What did you mean by a "point" of a stack in your earlier comment?